# Get (rich) type of an object in Python

Tags: python

Builtin type() only returns basic types. Is there a corresponding version that supports rich types as in the typing module? I'm trying to check whether a variable is of a specific type. For example:

```
# This function doesn't exist
>>> typing.type(ConnectionOptions)
>>> Dict[str, str]
```

Comment: look at the `isinstance (object, type)` function, https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance. `isinstance (your_own_object, ConnectionOptions)`, true if your_own_object is type of ConnectionOptions

Comment: This doesn't return the type, though. Is there a way to actually check the type of a variable? There must be, since IDE displays it. Or do they test for all possible types?

Comment: @Nijan Could you describe why you need this functionality? Checking for types in Python is generally considered an anti-pattern. The IDE is likely doing meta-analysis by reading your source code.

Comment: I see, the same thing you use type() for. To check if a parameter to a public class method call is of the right type. If not type(connect) != Connection: raise ValueError

Answer (score 0):

You can check variable name with error handling. Use  *try-except* statement.

```
try:
  Dict[str, str]

except NameError:
   print("Oops!  That was not a variable name")
```

There is more information here. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. That runs, but it doesn't do anything.